# How to limit the number of factors in facet_wrap() to plot for only top N factors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am working with Covid data at districts level & trying to plot Cases `timeseries` for **Districts** using `facet_wrap()`.

Some States have lots of districts and all of that wont fit so I want to **limit** the **facet_wrap** to **top N** districts.

I have tried to **reorder** the `facet_wrap()` by `fct_reorder(Districts)` but that only reorders & produces plot for all the districts.

Is there a way I can get **top N levels** of those `fct_reorder(Districts)` and plot only those **top N** or if there is any option to control the **number of facets** in `facet_wrap` ?

**df:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

file_url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_districts.csv"

df_districts <- read.csv(url(file_url))

df_districts <- df_districts %>% 
mutate(Date = ymd(Date))
```

**I have tried:**

```
df_districts %>% 
  filter(State == "Rajasthan",
         Date != max(Date),
         !is.na(Daily_confirmed)) %>% 

  # group_by(District, Date) %>% 
  # slice_max(order_by = Daily_confirmed, n = 20) %>% 
  
  mutate(District = fct_reorder(District, Daily_confirmed, 
                                .fun = max, .desc = TRUE)) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Daily_confirmed)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~District)
```

Comment: What about `dplyr::top_n()`?

Comment: As for facets on a page, you might adapt [`ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/facet_wrap_paginate.html) to your needs (though it does not handle the ordering, just page-by-page ... and this would be a slight mis-use of it :-).

Comment: @Taufi thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem in multiple time series just by `top_n` or `slice_max`

Comment: @r2evans `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate` this is actually great and solves the problem to some extent. I think this a better suited to my need. Appreciate your continuing help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to summarize the table by whatever precedence you need (e.g., `sum(Daily_confirmed)`), then take the top "n" by that sorted variable.

```r
df_districts %>%
  group_by(District) %>%
  summarize(daily = sum(Daily_confirmed)) %>%
  slice_max(daily, n = 10)
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#    District daily
#    <chr>    <int>
#  1 Jaipur   99843
#  2 Jodhpur  72443
#  3 Kota     39442
#  4 Alwar    34650
#  5 Udaipur  31297
#  6 Bikaner  26144
#  7 Ajmer    25866
#  8 Bhilwara 19922
#  9 Pali     16589
# 10 Sikar    15031
```

Using this data, we can `left_join` the original data back in on `District` (removing `daily` first, if desired), and your subset will have just those districts.

```r
out <- df_districts %>%
  group_by(District) %>%
  summarize(daily = sum(Daily_confirmed)) %>%
  slice_max(daily, n = 10) %>%
  select(-daily) %>%
  left_join(df_districts, by = "District")
out
# # A tibble: 3,660 x 11
#    District Date       State     Confirmed Recovered Deceased Other Tested Daily_confirmed Daily_Recovered Daily_Deceased
#    <chr>    <date>     <chr>         <int>     <int>    <int> <int>  <int>           <int>           <int>          <int>
#  1 Jaipur   2021-04-27 Rajasthan    100651     68325      659     0 968783            3289             989             21
#  2 Jaipur   2021-04-26 Rajasthan     97362     67336      638     0 968783            2878             961             11
#  3 Jaipur   2021-04-25 Rajasthan     94484     66375      627     0 968783            3145             648             13
#  4 Jaipur   2021-04-24 Rajasthan     91339     65727      614     0 968783            3260             657              9
#  5 Jaipur   2021-04-23 Rajasthan     88079     65070      605     0 968783            3036             767             13
#  6 Jaipur   2021-04-22 Rajasthan     85043     64303      592     0 968783            2317             658             11
#  7 Jaipur   2021-04-21 Rajasthan     82726     63645      581     0 968783            3101             551              5
#  8 Jaipur   2021-04-20 Rajasthan     79625     63094      576     0 968783            1875             413              9
#  9 Jaipur   2021-04-19 Rajasthan     77750     62681      567     0 968783            2011             528             11
# 10 Jaipur   2021-04-18 Rajasthan     75739     62153      556     0 968783            1963             258              4
# # ... with 3,650 more rows
```

For comparison,

```r
table(df_districts$District)
#          Ajmer          Alwar       Banswara          Baran         Barmer      Bharatpur       Bhilwara        Bikaner 
#            366            366            366            362            366            366            366            366 
#       BSF Camp          Bundi    Chittorgarh          Churu          Dausa        Dholpur      Dungarpur       Evacuees 
#            356            335            366            366            366            366            366            366 
#     Ganganagar    Hanumangarh       Italians         Jaipur      Jaisalmer         Jalore       Jhalawar      Jhunjhunu 
#            342            366            366            366            366            356            366            366 
#        Jodhpur        Karauli           Kota         Nagaur    Other State           Pali     Pratapgarh      Rajsamand 
#            366            366            366            366            366            366            366            366 
# Sawai Madhopur          Sikar         Sirohi           Tonk        Udaipur 
#            366            366            355            366            366 

table(out$District)
#    Ajmer    Alwar Bhilwara  Bikaner   Jaipur  Jodhpur     Kota     Pali    Sikar  Udaipur 
#      366      366      366      366      366      366      366      366      366      366
```

Comment: thanks @r2evans this works well but isn't there any shortcut to access `sorted` `top N factor levels` after applying `fct_reorder()` ? I was also thinking of the way as you have demonstrated but by this approach it makes the computation twice on same `df` & I will be using this on free version of shiny so trying to keep RAM usage to minimum.

Comment: If you don't want to preprocess the frame, then what existing column in the full 13K row frame is what you want to sort the Districts on? For example, in my code above, we effectively sort on the `sum` of the daily confirmed cases, but that's on a summary of the data. I don't know that you can easily `fct_reorder` the factors of `District` on a single column of the full frame.

Comment: Well it has to be sorted based on `max(Daily_confirmed)` only for Top N districts and your approach is absolute right but I was just thinking that if I have already `reordered` the `factors` using `fct_reorder` then if I could just use the factor levels in that order to limit the number of facets then it doesn't need any more processing. But your answer is absolute correct & even `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate` is also wonderful as it can be used on my piece of code as well. Thanks alot again @r2evans :)

Comment: Realize that `ggforce` builds all facets internally, and then only displays the top "n", so it works but may not be efficient (if plot-rendering time is important to you). I don't think you can use `fct_reorder` on a summary-statistic of a frame, it requires strict equal-length vectors. Granted, this is really easy to add outside of `dplyr`, so if you run into computation/memory issues, then (1) summarize with `aggregate`, (2) produce an ordered vector of all 37 districts, then (3) `mutate(District=factor(District, levels=myvec))`, that's as memory-efficient as you can get, I think.

Comment: yes I think I will have to resort to this approach only as you suggested as the data is increasing day by day so I have to be conscious of both size of data & computation requirement. Thank you so much for all the research & solution and the effort that you have put in to give me best possible scenario for my requirement. Really appreciate it :))